# Java 3d ColorCube Serialization errors

Tags: java, serialization, java-3d

Try to writing a program which create binary file of java 3d objects(such as sphere, colorcube...) for later use. But before doing this I have to serialize the objects, but I can't do it, error occurred.

lets see the program ----

The following class is the main class which create a ColorCube object and write to binary file

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import java.io.*;

public class SerializeDemo {

   public static void main(String [] args) {

   DoSerialize e = new DoSerialize();
   e.cc = new ColorCube(1.4);

   try {
     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("e://objectFile.txt");
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

     try {

     out.writeObject(e);
     }catch(NotSerializableException i)
       {i.printStackTrace();}

     out.close();
     fileOut.close();
    }catch(IOException i)
    {i.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

This is the serializable class ---

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;

public class DoSerialize implements java.io.Serializable {
  public ColorCube cc;
}
```

And the errors are ----

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
  at SerializeDemo.main(SerializeDemo.java:25)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

So how to overcome this problem?
Please help.
Thanks......

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the object you attempt to serialize does not implement the serializable interface, so therefore you can not serialize it through standard Java means.

You have to either serialize the object manually, which in this case means get all public properties and save them to a file, then read it in the same order, or attempt to use reflection to get all accessible members and find getters.

The first way is extremely tedious if used for many objects, the second is relatively slow. And unfortunately neither gives you any guarantee that it will work properly.